# "Robber's hand" as a metonym for robber

Tags: word-usage, metonyms

Is there a way to talk about a robber like this?

In Swedish there is a metonym for robber: "rånarhand", lit "robbers's hand".
And you could use it as: "not safe from robber's hand"

Is there a similar expression in English? I've tried to google it but I can only find people chopping off burglars' hands ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Keeping one's laptop etc] **safe from thieving hands**

is idiomatic if a little dated nowadays.

A typical example is *Keeping your laptop safe from thieving hands is often a difficult task ...* [[National Home Security Month](http://www.homesecuritymonth.com/best-ways-secure-laptop/)]

Answer (score 0):

A related slang phrase is ***five-finger discount***, which is defined by
[Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/five-finger_discount),
[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/five-finger-discount),
[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/five-finger+discount),
[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Five%20finger%20discount),
[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/five-finger_discount), and
[Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/five-finger-discount)
as “stealing” or “shoplifting” (i.e., stealing from a store).

I recall learning this term as meaning, specifically,
theft committed  *by employee(s) of the store*,
but I guess that was a misunderstanding;
I don’t see that nuance in any of the definitions.

Also, Wiktionary refers to [***sticky fingers***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sticky_fingers)
and defines it as “an inclination to steal”
or “a petty thief or petty thieves.”